# start image swap javascript from fixed server time

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a very simple mobile site for a charity and they want to show their own ad banners for local supporting businesses on the bottom. I've got a simple Javascript which swaps the image banner every 10 seconds for the next in the sequence:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var rotator = document.getElementById("adBox");
    var images = rotator.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++)
    {
      images[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    var counter = 1;
    setInterval(function ()
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
       {
          images[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       images[counter].style.display = "block";
       counter++;
       if (counter == images.length)
       {
         counter = 0;
       }
    }, 7000); //1000 = 1 second
};

<body ontouchstart="">
    <div id="adBox">
        <img src="_/ads/1.jpg" alt="One" width="320" height="70">
        <img src="_/ads/2.jpg" alt="Two" width="320" height="70">
        <img src="_/ads/3.jpg" alt="Three" width="320" height="70">
    <div>
</body>
```

However this resets and goes back to the start of the sequence when you load a different page. What I want to do is start the sequence at a fixed server time (say midnight) and just cycle through, so that when you load a new page, you don't go back to the start of the banners but go to the 'ad for that server time'.

I think this is the simplest and fairest way for the ads. I did look at using an iFrame but it would mean the main site would have to sit in one and I believe the support of iFrames on touch devices is not great (which would be a major issue for this).

Comment: Fairest way, you say. If my ad ended up being displayed only between 2am and 3am every day, I'd beg to differ. :)

Comment: Would you mind to add some HTML source code? So we don't need to assemble our own HTML code.

Comment: @bzim heh! Fortunately there's only a handful so they'll cycle trough very quickly and many many time throughout the day.

Comment: @reporter: I'ved added to the post - hopefully it's enough, let me know if not (pretty new to StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.

Sounds like you don't even need the images to 'rotate'.

How about something like this:

```
 Case(serverTime)
     If( 00.00 -> 04.00 )[ show ad #1 ]
     If( 04.01 -> 08.00 )[ show ad #2 ]
     If( 08.01 -> 12.00 )[ show ad #3 ]
     If( 12.01 -> 14.00 )[ show ad #4 ]
```

Obviously the above isn't valid code but you get the idea ?

Comment: I think that's the author asked for. It is just the question how he will achive it.

Comment: yes, this does sound like it is along the line I want to go. I'm just a html/css guy though so could you perhaps outline how it works in a bit more detail so I can try and work it out with my limited JS knowledge?

Comment: Basically in English, it says: if the server time is between midnight and 4am, show ad 1, if it's between 4.01am and 8.00am, show ad 2 etc. I'll put some more detail in presently . . .

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, I think this is a bit beyond my very limited JS knowledge. I've tried to pull apart the examples on those pages and re-assemble them into something that would work but no success. I'll keep Googling to find something closer that I can work with. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about your request a long while and I think I've got a solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var pictureArray = new Array
                (
                  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0eb8371e227b5f9993968b5f90f2a1d8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG", 
                  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9be5d328127c377109b295b5941733fb?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
                  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9e84f23bd4c8b566e466a2d4d7fc5ed4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
                );
                var counter = 0;
                var currentHour = new Date().getHours();
                if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour < 16)
                {
                    counter = 1;
                } else if (currentHour >=16 && currentHour <= 23) {
                    counter = 2;
                }
                var rotator = document.getElementById("adBox");
                var images = rotator.getElementsByTagName("img");
                images[0].src = pictureArray[counter];
                setInterval(function ()
                {
                    images[0].src = pictureArray[counter];
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == pictureArray.length)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                }
                , 7000); //1000 = 1 second
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ontouchstart="">
        <div id="adBox">
            <img src="" alt="pic" width="320" height="70">
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I changed your code a little bit, because in my eyes your original way was to complicated. I hope that is it what you want -better what I understood- to archive.

Note: Javascript works on client side so it takes the time from local computer. If you want to take the time from server, you have to put it to your HTML output.